# Not display "update" button on apple store always display "open" button - ios

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone

My App version 2.0 available on the apple store now I am uploaded a new version 2.1 and successfully uploaded but users did not display the new version with the "update" button on the apple store.
one user tried to update after 7 days but still display the "open" button.
we also checked "Auto-update" also off.PFA
if anyone has a solution then give me one.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the app is not already updated?...

Comment: And, are you sure that the the update isn't "pending developer release"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disabling Testflight mode it's working fine. So anyone faces this issue then please disable Testflight mode.

**Follow the below steps for disable test flight:-**

1.Open app store-->click on app-->Click on test flight

2.Remove all internal testers as well as remove External group

3.Expire all the build

4.After uploading new build display in testflight.So expire for testing.

5.After that select bild for production.

**Need to follow below steps in every testflight tester:-**

1.open testflight app

2.click on app

3.click on stop testing

i applied above all changes and now it's working proper.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have provided insufficient or wrong information.

Based on your answer it looks like you have installed app with development profile and you were trying to update it with production app.

That's why it is not showing Update button.

Comment: No, Due to test flight beta faced this issue. No problem related to certificates.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that application status is not pending developer release. So,
Try to change language/time zone of your device from Dutch to English.

Comment: pkc456 
i tried after change language but the same thing display

Answer (score -1):

Possible Solutions:

1. If you have enabled phase release than it might take some time (Days).
2. Check and update Region/Country in app store or device if required.
3. Checking supported iOS version and device might help.

Let me know if you find any other solutions.